# Sony IR API and Xperia tablet Z2

Tags: sony

I wrote an IR app for the Xperia tablet S which works well but I have just upgraded to the Z2. This app is not working very well on the Z2 but the Sony IR Remote Demo app which again works well on the S, does not work at all on the Z2.

Does anyone know if there is something different in the way the IR API is implemented in the Z2?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my problem was timing, I was sending the IR codes too quickly and overrunning the buffer. Although I had increased the delay between sending codes it was not nearly enough.

The answer to my question would be that there is no changes to the IR API.